# Internal server error with large file in django

Tags: python, django, internal-server-error, file-read

I have the following problem; I have a module that reads a 1.5Gb file and then processes it with it. If I run it in the Python console it works normally, however if I make the call from that file read in a django view it returns error 500 before it highlights the entire file load.

How to proceed?

Comment: Look in the webserver error log for an error message.

Comment: I'll make a wild guess that the web server process doesn't have permission to access the file location.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to tell you I'm using ajax to call this module

Comment: Ajax shouldn't matter.  If you're getting a 500 server error, that's coming from the webserver, and it should log some kind of error message.

Comment: You were correct, I was not being able to find the file, I fixed the location and it worked. Puts a reply telling me to check the location of the file that I've marked as correct

Answer (score 1):

Since the shell is executing the complete request, the request could be getting timed out due to app server or web server:

- If using Nginx as web server, try increasing read time out: proxy_read_timeout < a high value in sec >
- If using Gunicorn as app server, try increasing this as well:
  TIMEOUT=< a high value in sec >
- If using wsgi as app server, try either:
  http-timeout=< a high value in sec >.